# How to copy files from kubernetes Pods to local system

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to copy files from Kubernetes Pods to my local system. I am getting the below error while running following command:

```
kubectl cp aks-ssh2-6cd4948f6f-fp9tl:/home/azureuser/test.cap ./test.cap
```

Output:

> tar: home/azureuser/test: Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar:
>   Exiting with failure status due to previous errors error:
>   home/azureuser/test no such file or directory

I could see the file under above given path. I am really confused.

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 266):

As stated in`kubectl` help:

```
kubectl cp --help
Copy files and directories to and from containers.
Examples:
# !!!Important Note!!!
# Requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container
# image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'kubectl cp' will fail.

# Copy /tmp/foo_dir local directory to /tmp/bar_dir in a remote pod in the default namespace
kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir <some-pod>:/tmp/bar_dir

# Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in a specific container
kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-pod>:/tmp/bar -c <specific-container>

# Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in namespace <some-namespace>
kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/bar

# Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar

Options:
-c, --container='': Container name. If omitted, the first container in the pod will be chosen

Usage:
kubectl cp <file-spec-src> <file-spec-dest> [options]

Use "kubectl options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).
```

You can also login to your `Containter` and check if file is there:

```
kubectl exec -it aks-ssh2-6cd4948f6f-fp9tl /bin/bash
ls -la /home/azureuser/test.cap
```

If this still doesn't work, try:

> You may try to copy your files to workdir and then retry to copy them using just their names. It's weird, but it works for now.

Consider advice of [kchugalinskiy](https://github.com/kchugalinskiy) here [#58692](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58692).

Comment: Lesson: don't forget to put "namespace or project-name(if openshift)" also it could not cp linked file (getting `tar: Removing leading / from member names` error)

Comment: Also note if you're getting `is outside target destination` when trying to copy from pod to local, then a solution that seemed to work is making it so the local destination is relative. e.g.  `kubectl -c my-service cp namesapce/pod:/tmp/remoteFile1 localFilename `

Answer (score 70):

Let's say you are copying file from bin folder to local system. The command is

```
kubectl cp default/POD_NAME:bin/FILE_NAME /Users/username/FILE_NAME
```

You can connect to POD to verify if you are specifying correct file name

```
kubectl exec -ti POD_NAME bash
```

Comment: Is there a way to copy files from Kubernetes driver to all the pods? This is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71822625/looking-for-a-way-to-copy-files-to-all-aks-pods-instead-of-just-the-driver

Comment: E.g. pattern: `kubectl cp -namespace MyNamespace MyPod:MyFilename MyFilename`

Answer (score 44):

According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands

`kubectl cp <file-spec-src> <file-spec-dest>` is equivalent to using

`kubectl exec -n <some-namespace> <some-pod> -- tar cf - <src-file> | tar xf - -C <dest-file>`

So technically if you do not have tar installed on the pod, you can do `kubectl exec -n <some-namespace> <some-pod> -- cat <src-file> > <dest-file>`

Assuming the file is small or already compressed, the effect should be the same, except you cannot use cat on a directory or a set of files.

Comment: Million thanks! Saved my day. But how does it work? How do pod understand where to put a file as we just specify a folder which pod is not aware of?

Comment: It works because you are running command(s) in your local terminal and piping the output of one to the other (or into a file, in the case of the `cat`).

In the `tar` example, you are running the local command `kubectl` and piping its output into the local command `tar`. The `kubectl` command just happens to be running commands in the pod and transparently bringing the output of that command to your local terminal.

Comment: Beware that this `cat` trick may break binary files. I did that with a Java heap dump and the file was modified during the transfer. The `md5sum` of the file on the pod didn't match the `md5sum` of the file I got locally. The file was completely broken.

Answer (score 30):

The command in the question posted is absolutely right. As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52408599/5362795) before, this particular issue seems to be a missing `tar` binary in the container. I actually did not know it was needed, but confirmed that the pod has it:

```
# find / -name tar
/bin/tar
/usr/lib/mime/packages/tar
/usr/share/doc/tar
```

My error was using `.` to copy to the current directory (works with `cp` and `scp`) because it needs the full path, as shown in the original question:

```
kubectl cp pod-name-shown-in-get-pods:path/to/filename /local/dir/filename
```

But *not*:

```
kubectl cp pod-name-shown-in-get-pods:path/to/filename .
```

Which gives:

```
error: open .: is a directory
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

Now the `tar` in the error message makes sense!

Note that if there is a leading `/` in the *source* path, as in the following example:

```
kubectl cp pod-name-shown-in-get-pods:/etc/resolv.conf /local/dir/resolv.conf
```

You would also see:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

However, the warning can be ignored, as the file would still copied. Use `etc/resolv.conf` instead of `/etc/resolv.conf` in the above example, to copy without the warning.

Comment: It is strange why leading `/` is giving warning.

Answer (score 17):

kubectl cp command is already mentioned by some of the users on this thread.

```
kubectl cp <pod-id>:<path> <local-path> -n <namespace> -c <specific_container>
```

Note that to run this command **tar** utility should already be installed on the pod.

However I have come across few errors while running this command on **windows** PowerShell.

```
PS P:\Users\nstty\Downloads\k8s-diags> kubectl cp dremio-master-0:/var/log/dremio/server.log P:\Users\nstty\Downloads\k8s-diags\server-logs\
error: one of src or dest must be a local file specification
```

**error: one of src or dest must be a local file specification**

When running this command on windows, don't use the full path of the local system. Use relative path instead (. or ..). Now using relative path in the below command but getting a different error.

```
PS P:\Users\nstty\Downloads\k8s-diags> kubectl cp dremio-master-0:/var/log/dremio/server.log .
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
error: open .: is a directory
```

**error: open .: is a directory**

If you are copying a file, then in the local path use the relative path along with the file name that you want for the copied file. kubectl will first create this file and then copy the contents to this file. Below is the working command.

```
PS P:\Users\nstty\Downloads\k8s-diags> kubectl cp dremio-master-0:/var/log/dremio/server.log .\server-logs\server.log
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

**tar: Removing leading `/' from member names**

This message is just a warning from tar utility in your pod. The file should be copied to your local system.

**Alternate option**: If you want to avoid kubectl cp, here is [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74191433/6563567) which we use.

Answer (score 13):

"kubectl cp" command is used to copy files from pods to local path and vice versa

1. Copying file from pod to local

   > kubectl cp <pod_name>:<file_path> <destination_path>
2. Copying file from specific container of pod to local

   > kubectl cp <pod_name>:<file_path> <destination_path> -c specific_container
3. Copying file from local to pod

   > kubectl cp <local_source_path> <pod_name>:<destination_path>

Answer (score 8):

```
kubectl cp <pod-id>:<path> <destination-path> -n <namespace>
```

Worked for me.

Comment: The `<path>` should start from the `/` but not with `/`.

ex: 
```kubectl cp <pod-id>:path/from/root/dir <destination-path> -n <namespace>```

Answer (score 4):

You can mount a local directory into the pod.

Update your aks-ssh yaml file:

```
spec:
  ...
  containers:
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test-dir
      mountPath: /home/azureuser
    ...
  volumes:
  - name: test-dir
    hostPath:
      path: /path/to/your/local/dir
```

Now you can access your files in the local directory.

Comment: That doesn’t help if the machine you’re calling from isn’t one of the Kubernetes nodes; for instance, if you’re using a managed cloud Kubernetes installation and trying to get content out of it on to your local laptop.

Answer (score 4):

For people working on a Windows machine there is an additional gotcha:  As at October 2021 you cannot include a drive letter in your local path.

So if you were to try a command like:

`kubectl cp aks-ssh2-6cd4948f6f-fp9tl:/home/azureuser/test.cap C:/Temp/Test`

you would get this error because `kubectl cp` sees the colon in the Windows path as the separator between a pod name and the path within the pod.
So it would see `C:/Temp/Test` as a pod named "C" with a path "/Temp/Test"

The way to get around this is to use a relative Windows path instead of an absolute path.  It will need to be relative to your current working directory.

So if my current working directory is `C:\Users\JoeBloggs` and I wanted to copy down to `C:\Temp\Test` I'd need to use the command:

`kubectl cp aks-ssh2-6cd4948f6f-fp9tl:/home/azureuser/test.cap ../../Temp/Test`

Note that this issue looks like it may be fixed soon.  See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/94165

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone could met this error

```
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
error: open .: is a directory
```

Which induced by the following command

```
 kc cp -n monitoring <pod name>:/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini ./

 kc cp -n monitoring <pod name>:/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini ./default.ini
```

To solve it, we should add a destination folder per [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58692)

`kc cp -n monitoring <pod name>:/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini ./tmp/default.ini`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
kubectl cp "namespace"/"pod_name":"path_in_pod" "local_path"
```

Example:

```
kubectl cp mynamespace/mypod:var/www/html/index.html \Users\myuser\Desktop\index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone uses windows pods, it may be hard to get files copied to the pods from local machine with those linux paths for kubectl cp command:

Procedure to copy files from local machine to kubernetes pod: (especially windows container)

1. I want to copy node.aspx from my local machine to
   podname:\c:\inetpub\wwwroot
2. First upload Node.aspx to your cloud drive, path will be
   /home/{your_username} in my case /home/pranesh
3. Then find out the pod name, in my case its
   aspx-deployment-84597d88f5-pk5nh, follow below command

```
PS /home/pranesh> kubectl cp /home/pranesh/Node.aspx aspx-deployment-84597d88f5-pk5nh:/Node.aspx
```

4. This copies the file to c drive of container,
5. then move file from c drive to required path with powershell

```
PS /home/pranesh> kubectl exec aspx-deployment-84597d88f5-pk5nh powershell "Copy-Item "C:\Node.aspx" -Destination "C:\inetpub\wwwroot""
```

6. Use the reverse procedure for copying from container to cloud drive and download.

Comment: After copying my.log in the windows container to root of c, command to copy locally was `kubectl cp my-namespace/my-pod-name:my.log ./my.log`

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem by set the source folder to be relative path. 
If the file location is /home/azureuser/test.cap, and working dir is /home/azureuser/, the cmd is

kubectl cp aks-ssh2-6cd4948f6f-fp9tl:test.cap ./test.cap

Answer (score 0):

kubectl cp will not work if your container does not have tar command in the PATH. From your error it sees like tar command is not available on your container.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58512
Please explore other options

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes gives a file not found error when user does not have permissions to a pod. That was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my side the issue was with having multiple containers inside the pod:

```
kubectl cp -c grafana \
    metrics/grafana-5c4f76b49b-p88lc:/etc/grafana \
    ./grafana/etc
```

so set the container name with `-c grafana` and properly prefix the namespace of the pod in my case `metrics/`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method on Azure and it worked:

```
kubectl cp 'POD NAME':xyz.json test

kubectl cp is the command for copying

POD NAME =  vote-app
```

`xyz.json` is the file that needs to be copied from pod
the test is the file created in the drive of the AZURE directory...

So final command would be:

```
kubectl cp vote-app:xyz.json test
```

test will get generated in Azure Directory and later u can download `test` file from the download option of Azure
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to Copy File from Kubernetes Pod to Local**

1. Go to the local path you want to copy.....
   Then Enter the below command
   **kubectl cp pod_name -c <container_name_if_present>:<path_of_the file> <name_of_the_file> <desired_name_of_the_file>**

**Note:**
**<Path_of_the_file>** can be obtained by Executing "**pwd**" at the location of the file inside the pod.

2. To copy files from local to pod
   **kubectl cp <path_of_the file_in_local>/<file_name> <pod_name>:**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this thread while searching for similar errors I’ve encountered when attempting to copy a file from my Kubernetes pod to my local host. In my specific case, I realized that I need to specify the path to the pod’s file system, which resides under /host:

1 SSH into my pod hosted on an AKS cluster:

```
ssh -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -p 2022 -W %h:%p azureuser@127.0.0.1' azureuser@10.xx.xx.xx
```

1.1. Check the user ID:

```
azureuser@aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009:~$ whoami
azureuser
azureuser@aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009:~$ id
uid=1000(azureuser) gid=1000(azureuser) groups=1000(azureuser),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),119(netdev),120(lxd)
```

1.2. Create a test file:

```
azureuser@aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009:~$ echo "test" > test.txt
azureuser@aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009:~$ pwd
/home/azureuser
azureuser@aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009:~$ ls
test.txt
```

2.1. From my local host, I attempted to search for the file under the default / directory as ‘root’:

```
PS D:\> kubectl exec -i -t node-debugger-aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009-sbncw -c debugger -- whoami
 root     

PS D:\> kubectl exec -i -t node-debugger-aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009-sbncw -c debugger -- id
 uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)     

PS D:\> kubectl exec -i -t node-debugger-aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009-sbncw -c debugger -- ls /home/azureuser
 ls: /home/azureuser: No such file or directory
 command terminated with exit code 1
```

2.2. However, the file is actually located in /host, which corresponds to the pod’s file system (I’m still wrapping my head around this):

```
PS D:\> kubectl exec -i -t node-debugger-aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009-sbncw -c debugger -- ls /host/home/azureuser
 test.txt
```

2.3. Now that I’ve corrected the path, the cp command should work:

```
PS D:\Repos> kubectl cp node-debugger-aks-nodepool1-39416372-vmss000009-sbncw:host/home/azureuser/test.txt \test.txt  

PS D:\> dir \test.txt

    Directory: D:\

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          21/02/2024    13:44              5 test.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get kubectl to work for this. Was getting error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

This worked for me instead:

`docker cp CONTAINERID:FILEWITHPATH DESTFILENAME`

where "CONTAINERID" was retrieved by calling `docker ps`.