# azcopy installation on container error - "panic: mkdir : no such file or directory"

Tags: azure, docker, azcopy

I'm trying run azcopy v10 inside a container to export some files to azure blob storage.

To include azcopy utility in the container image, I have use below instruction in the Dockerfile.

```
 RUN /bin/bash -c 'wget https://azcopyvnext.azureedge.net/release20220511/azcopy_linux_amd64_10.15.0.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf azcopy_linux_amd64_10.15.0.tar.gz && \
  cp ./azcopy_linux_amd64_*/azcopy /usr/bin/ && \
  chmod 775 /usr/bin/azcopy && \
  rm azcopy_linux_amd64_10.15.0.tar.gz && \
  rm -rf azcopy_linux_amd64_*'
```

However seeing below error when I run the azcopy command.

```
ns@master-0:/opt/myapp$ azcopy
panic: mkdir : no such file or directory

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/common.PanicIfErr(...)
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/common/lifecyleMgr.go:674
main.main()
        /home/vsts/work/1/s/main.go:55 +0x4c5
```

Not sure which file/dir the error message is referring to. Any suggestions will be helpful.

**Edit 1:** updated download link of azcopy to a static version rather than download a latest version

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the Go code that produces that error?  What directory are you trying to [`os.Mkdir()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Mkdir)?  What's the main container `CMD` in the Dockerfile, and is there more important setup you're not showing?

Comment: @DavidMaze There is no go code I'm using.. azcopy utility is probably using Golang and hence the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue in github:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/903

I was able to get azcopy working by setting below env variable as mentioned in the github link.

```
mkdir /opt/myapp/azlogs
export AZCOPY_LOG_LOCATION=/opt/myapp/azlogs
```

This is basically the log location for azcopy. I'm thinking of making this env variable part of the image rather than having to type it out every time.

**EDIT 1:**
I came across another error.

```
panic: mkdir plans: permission denied
```

looks like azcopy wants to create a **plans** directory on current working dir. So ensure that the user you are running azcopy as has permissions to create a new folder on the current working dir.