# Migrate JupyterHub app state to new k8s cluster? (AWS EKS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jupyter, jupyterhub, amazon-eks

In a scenario where we need to re-provision kubernetes cluster (specifically, AWS-managed kubernetes, “EKS”) – is it possible to migrate JupyterHub application state from the old cluster to the new cluster? Ideally, we would like to migrate everything. But it would be sufficient to just migrate user notebook files.

Details:
JupyterHub (0.8.2) was deployed to AWS-managed kubernetes using helm v2.13

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your `deployment`, I would copy all `yaml` files responsible for deploying the JupyterHub and copy the data from `Persistent Volumes`.

You could do that by using `kubectl cp` this is nicely explain in this post [How to copy files from kubernetes Pods to local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407277/how-to-copy-files-from-kubernetes-pods-to-local-system).

It all depends on how you deployed the JupyterHub, you need to provide more details regarding how was that deployed and what is exactly being used and how.

Comment: what kind of additional details would be helpful? I updated the question to reflect the JupyterHub version, how it was deployed (helm/tiller) and the helm version