# How to copy files from a windows kubernetes pod container

Tags: windows, kubernetes

I have had some difficulties copying files from a kubernetes pod container (**windows** nodes) to my local linux subsystem on windows 10:

```
t@11DT:/mnt/c/dev/auto$ kubectl cp a8677:c:\testlog2.txt .
tar: Removing leading drive letter from member names
error: tar contents corrupted
t@11DT:/mnt/c/dev/auto$ kubectl cp a8677:/c/testlog2.txt ./
tar: /c/testlog2.txt: Couldn't find file: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
t@11DT:/mnt/c/dev/auto$ kubectl cp a8677:c:\testlog2.txt ./
tar: Removing leading drive letter from member names
error: tar contents corrupted
t@11DT:/mnt/c/dev/auto$ kubectl cp a8677:c:/testlog2.txt ./
tar: Removing leading drive letter from member names
error: tar contents corrupted
t@11DT:/mnt/c/dev/auto$ kubectl cp a8677:c:/testlog2.txt ./t2.txt
tar: Removing leading drive letter from member names
error: tar contents corrupted
t@11DT:/mnt/c/dev/auto$ kubectl cp a8677:c:\testlog2.txt ./t2.txt
tar: Removing leading drive letter from member names
error: tar contents corrupted
```

The file `c:\testlog2.txt` definitely existed in pod a8677. But how to address `c:\testlog2.txt` appropriately?

---

**Note:**

Some moderators suggested to close this question, as it is a duplicate of [How to copy files from kubernetes Pods to local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407277/how-to-copy-files-from-kubernetes-pods-to-local-system) . The existing question is about how to copy files in general between linux nodes in kubernetes clusters and linux local systems. This information is covered in the Kubernetes documentation (https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/container_debugging/copying_container_files.html).

This question here is specifically about **windows** containers. It seems to be neither covered in the kubernetes documentation, nor in any other question I found on stackoverflow. Many things that are straightforward in kubernetes linux nodes need a bit extra research for windows nodes.

I therefore do not think it is a duplicate.

Comment: No - updating the post.

Comment: looks to be a limitation now: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77310  my workaround is to copy to file to 'current dir', then copy out: 
1. do a in container file copy/move (using kubectl exec ); 2. kubectl cp a8677:testlog2.txt .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct way is, to omit the drive letter:

`kubectl cp <pod_name>:filename`

for example:

`kubectl cp a8677:testlog2.txt ./t2.txt`

If the file is inside a subdirectory, the path needs to contain slashes, and no backslashes:

```
kubectl cp a8677:my/file/path/file.txt ./myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can copy files, just give your log path and file name.

> kubectl cp -n namespace pod_name:logs/file_name file_name

Answer (score 0):

CHECK THIS!!!

## Open a new terminal and run this command

> kubectl cp --help

##### Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in namespace

> tar cf - /tmp/foo | kubectl exec -i -n   -- tar xf - -C /tmp/bar

##### Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally

> kubectl exec -n   -- tar cf - /tmp/foo | tar xf - -C /tmp/bar

##### Copy /tmp/foo_dir local directory to /tmp/bar_dir in a remote pod in the default namespace

> kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir :/tmp/bar_dir

##### Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in a specific container

> kubectl cp /tmp/foo :/tmp/bar -c

##### Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in namespace

> kubectl cp /tmp/foo /:/tmp/bar

##### Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally

> kubectl cp /:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).