# Move or change a volume namespace

Tags: kubernetes, storage, volume, kubernetes-pvc

We re-organise our namespaces in Kubernetes. We want to move our Persistent volume Claims created by a storageclass from one namespace to another.

(Our backup tool don't help).

Comment: What backup tools do you use ? 
I wonder if it is possible in `Velero`.

Comment: Velero seems to support [Restoring Into a Different Namespace](https://velero.io/docs/v1.5/restore-reference/#restoring-into-a-different-namespace).I don't use it . @matt_j

Answer (score 14):

### Option 1: use a backup tool

The easiest and safest option to migrate a pvc/pv to a new namespace is to use a backup tool (like [velero](https://velero.io/docs/v1.5/restore-reference/#restoring-into-a-different-namespace))

### Option 2: no backup tool (by hand)

This is undocumented.

In this exemple, we use VMware storage provider, but it should work with any storageClass.

### Prepare

Make a * **Backup** * **Backup** * **Backup** * **Backup** * **Backup** * !!!

well, if you do have a backup tool for kubernetes (like [velero](https://velero.io/docs/v1.5/restore-reference/#restoring-into-a-different-namespace)) you can restore directly in the target namespace, otherwise use `kubectl cp` as explained in [How to copy files from kubernetes Pods to local system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52407277/1260896)

Let's set some environment variable and backup the existing PV and PVC ressources

```
NAMESPACE1=XXX
NAMESPACE2=XXX
PVC=mypvc

kubectl get pvc -n $NAMESPACE1 $PVC -o yaml | tee /tmp/pvc.yaml

PV=pvc-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

kubectl get pv  $PV -o yaml | tee /tmp/pv.yaml
```

## Change ReclaimPolicy for PV

If your persistent volume (or storage provider) has persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy=Delete, make sure to change it to "Retain" to avoid data loss when removing the PVC below.

Run this:

```
kubectl patch pv "$PV" -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'
```

Then check:

```
kubectl describe pv "$PV" | grep -e Reclaim
```

### Remove the PVC

Manually delete the Persistent volume claim (you have a copy, right?).

```
kubectl delete -n "$NAMESPACE1" "$PVC"
```

### Modify the Persistent Volume (PV)

A PV is attached to a namespace when it's first used by a PVC. Furthermore, the PV become "attached" to the PVC (by it's `uid:`, not by it's name).

Change the namespace of the PV. Temporarily use PVC "name" to "lock" the PV for that PVC (rather than PVC uid).

```
"kubectl patch pv "$PV" -p '{"spec":{"claimRef":{"namespace":"'$NAMESPACE2'","name":"'$PVC'","uid":null}}}'
```

Check what we have now:

```
kubectl get pv "$PV" -o yaml | grep -e Reclaim -e namespace -e uid: -e name: -e claimRef | grep -v " f:"
```

### Create the new PVC

Create a PVC in the new namespace. Make sure to explicitly choose the PV to use (don't use StorageClass to provision the volume). Typically, you can copy the original PVC YAML, but drop `namespace:`, `selfLink:`, `uid:` in the section `metadata:`.

This command should work (it re-use the previous PVC), but you can use your own `kubectl apply` command.

```
grep -v -e "uid:" -e "resourceVersion:" -e "namespace:" -e "selfLink:"  /tmp/pvc.yml | kubectl -n "$NAMESPACE2" apply -f -
```

### Assign PVC to PV

At this point, the PV is bounded to the former PVC's name (but it may not work, and it is not the standard configuration). Running `kubectl describe -n "$NAMESPACE2" pvc "$PVC"`will complain with `Status:        Lost` and/or `Warning  ClaimMisbound`. So let's fix the problem:

Retrieve the new PVC's uid:

```
PVCUID=$( kubectl get -n "$NAMESPACE2" pvc "$PVC" -o custom-columns=UID:.metadata.uid --no-headers )
```

Then update the PV accordingly :

```
kubectl patch pv "$PV" -p '{"spec":{"claimRef":{"uid":"'$PVCUID'","name":null}}}'
```

After a few seconds the PV should be `Status:  Bound`.

### Restore PV ReclaimPolicy=Delete

(This step is optional. Needed to ensure PV is deleted when user delete the PVC)

Once the PV is in `Bound` state again, you can restore the reclaim policy if you want to preserve the original behaviour (i.e removing the PV when the PVC is removed) :

```
kubectl patch pv "$PV" -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Delete"}}'

## Check :
kubectl get pv $PV -o yaml | grep -e Reclaim -e namespace
```

Voilà

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer! Although I don't get why propose to anyone to restore reclaimPolicy back to `Delete`. If we mentioned backups in the beginning, then definitely reclaimPolicy should stay `Retain` to prevent unexpected data loss.

Comment: I performed this method, but It did not work with `storageClassName: nfs-client`, what I did is to backup the nfs directory and once the new pvc was created, I copied the content of the older one to it.

Answer (score 2):

I have migrated a **`pv`** that was with a storage class of **`storageClassName: nfs-client`** in a different way to another **`namespace`**.

The steps performed:

- Change the pvc policy to `Retain` (the default is `Delete`), it means that once the `pvc` is removed, **the `pv` resource will not be removed**.:

```bash
kubectl patch pvc <pvc-name> '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'
```

- Get the name of the pvc and copy it to another directory, taking into consideration its owner, permissions and everything (**the flags `-avR` of the `cp` command, are really important to achieve this task**).

```bash
dirpath=$(kubectl get pv <pvc-name> -o jsonpath="{.spec.nfs.path}")
\cp -avR ${dirpath} /tmp/pvc_backup
```

- Once it has been copied, you can proceed to remove the previous pvc and pv:

```bash
kubectl delete pvc <pvc-name>
kubectl delete pv <pv-name>
```

- Create the new pvc resource with your own yaml file `path/pvc.yaml`( for this example this was my pvc yaml file):

```bash
kubectl -n <target-namespace> create -f path/pvc.yaml
```

- Once created in the right `namespace`, proceed to copy the content of the backup directory to the new pvc created (**remember that you all need to do is to create the nfs pvc and the pv is automatically created**):

```bash
nfs_pvc_dir=$(kubectl -n <target-namespace> get pv <pv-name> -o jsonpath="{.spec.nfs.path}")
\cp -avR /tmp/pvc_backup/* ${nfs_pvc_dir}/
```

- Finally, proceed to bound your new pvc to a deployment or pod resource.

It was performed with `microk8s` on a public vps with a `nfs storage`:

- https://microk8s.io/docs
- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner

Greetings :)